# Share private assemblies between NT service and WCF service (without GAC)

Tags: wcf, windows-services, assemblies

I have a WCF service (.svc) and a NT service (.exe) that need to share private assemblies (without resorting to using the GAC).

Currently I have these two directory structures

\MyService\service.svc
\MyService\web.config
\MyService\bin\privateassembly.dll

An IIS virtual directory pointing to \MyService

and

\MyApplication\myapp.exe
\MyApplication\myapp.exe.config
\MyApplication\bin\privateassembly.dll

What I would like is to have everything in the same root directory AND share private assemblies, similarly to this...

\MyApplication\web\service.svc
\MyApplication\web\web.config
\MyApplication\service\myapp.exe
\MyApplication\service\myapp.exe.config
\MyApplication\bin\privateassembly.dll

I understand the above structure is impossible since assembly probing outside the applications directory is prohibited.

Any input in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx).

```
<probing privatePath="" />
```